# Как сделать раскадровку .GIF для анимации в Android проекте?

Tags: анимация, android

Посоветуйте бесплатную программу, которой можно разбить .GIF на отдельные файлы т.е. кадры.

Comment: а че бы гиф не вставить если он готовый?

Comment: изучаю drawable-ресурс типа animation-list, покадровая анимация короче говоря

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Freeware Gif Resizer for resizing animated gif online](http://toolson.net/GifResizer).

> Resize GIF (decrease, increase), extract GIF frames online by GIF Resizer